# Loop stops working as expected when wrapped around an 'if' statement or function

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and programming in general. I am trying to create a very simple guess the number game in the command line.

At the moment, the user has to give a range in which to guess, but I also want to give a default option. Previously I had [this function](https://gist.github.com/rafamadriz/675dca7fd9527dea1972c17e35445952#file-guess-game-rs-L27-L45) to just ask for range.

Here's how it looks trying to give a default range option.

```rs
fn get_range() -> Vec<i32> {
    println!("Press C for custom range or any key for default range");
    println!("Custom range");
    println!("Default range [0,10]");

    for line in stdin().lock().lines() {
        if line.unwrap().to_lowercase() == "c" {
            loop {
                let range_start: i32 = {
                    println!("\nStart of range:");
                    get_user_number().unwrap()
                };
                let range_end: i32 = {
                    println!("\nEnd of range (end is inclusive):");
                    get_user_number().unwrap()
                };

                if range_start < range_end {
                    return (range_start..=range_end).collect();
                } else {
                    println!("\nThe start of the range must be a lower number than the end!")
                }
            }
        } else {
            return (0..=10).collect();
        }
    }

    (0..=10).collect()
}
```

However, for some reason, the loop to ask for a custom range stops working properly once inside the if statement, I also tried to wrapped in a function but doesn't work neither. What happens is that it prints `Start of range` and it stops there, nothing works afterwards.

Other questions:

1. If I remove the last statement at the end of the function `(0..=10).collect()`. I get these errors from the Rust analyzer at the beginning of the *for* loop.

   > 1. mismatched types expected struct `Vec<i32>` found unit type `()` return
   >    a value for the case when the loop has zero elements to iterate on, or
   >    consider changing the return type to account for that possibility [E0308]
   > 2. the function expects a value to always be returned, but loops might run zero
   >    times [E0308]

   Doesn't everything inside the for loop returns a `Vec<i32>`? Why is there a mismatch in the types?
2. If I remove the else option then the default option doesn't work. I don't understand this because the *if* statement only happens when the user types <kbd>C</kbd>. Otherwise it skips the if and gets to the end of the function where a `Vec<i32>` is returned. Why do I have to explicitly put an *else* statement?

   Here's the [entire file](https://gist.github.com/rafamadriz/675dca7fd9527dea1972c17e35445952#file-guess-game-rs) in case you want more context. Note that the `get_range()` function is the original version of directly asking for a range instead of also giving a default option.

Finally, what are some recommendations for small projects to build? My next one is a simple [Neofetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neofetch) kind of program that gives some system information. I'm interested in command line tools and low level stuff like a kernel and OS's (but building a kernel or OS is still very far for my skills, hope to get there some day :)

Comment: I suspect `get_user_number()` tries to read from stdin, no? But you've already *locked* stdin here: `stdin().lock()`. And thus your program probably deadlocks.

Answer (score -1):

> Doesn't everything inside the for loop returns a Vec ? Why is
> there a mismatch in the types ?

The compiler investigated what would happen if there were no lines in `stdin().lock().lines()`. In that case, the for-loop will never execute, but a for-loop is an expression, and according to "Programming Rust (Revised 2nd Edition)", p. 143:

> Loops are expressions in Rust [which means they have a value which can
> be assigned to a variable], but the value of a while or for loop is
> always `()`, so their value isn't very useful.

That means the compiler replaces your whole for loop with `()`.     A similar thing happens here:

```
let numbers: [i32;0] = [];

let x = for number in numbers {
    println!("{number}");
};

println!("{:?}", x);

--output:--
()
```

The for loop never executed, but it evaluated to `()`.  As a result, if there are no lines in `stdin().lock().lines()` your for loop will be skipped and it will evaluate to `()`, and your function ends up returning `()`. But, you told the compiler that your function returns a vector:

```
fn get_range() -> Vec<i32> {
   ...
}
```

and `()` isn't a vector.  Hence, mismatched types, etc. Adding the line:

```
(0..=10).collect()
```

after the for loop, means your function will no longer return `()` if the for loop is skipped, which gets the compiler to shut up.

> If I remove the else option then the default option doesn't work. I
> don't understand this because the if statement only happens when the
> user types c. Otherwise it skips the if and gets to the end of the
> function where a Vec is returned. Why do I have to explicitly put
> an else statement ?

This has to do with expressions again.  An `if` is an expression, which means it produces a value which can be assigned to a variable, for instance:

```
let x = 2;

let result = if x==3 {"hello"} else {"goodbye"};

println!("{result}");

--output:--
goodbye
```

According to "Programming Rust (Revised 2nd Edition)", p. 138:

> ...an if without an else must always return `()`.

That implies that an `if expression` that returns something must also have an `else` arm which returns the same type.  Here's an example that runs afoul of that rule:

```
fn go(x: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut return_val =  0;

    return_val = if x==2 {4};

    return_val + 10
}
```

Output:

```
error[E0317]: `if` may be missing an `else` clause
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |     return_val = if x==2 {4};
  |                  ^^^^^^^^^-^
  |                  |        |
  |                  |        found here
  |                  expected integer, found `()`
  |
  = note: `if` expressions without `else` evaluate to `()`
  = help: consider adding an `else` block that evaluates to the expected type

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0317`.
```

The rule stated in "Programming Rust Revised 2nd" really *means*:

> ...an if without an else must always [evaluate to] `()`.

...because the following compiles without error:

```
fn go(x: i32) -> Vec<i32> {
    if x == 2 {
        return (30..=35).collect();
    };

    return (0..=10).collect(); //This could also be written without `return` and no semi-colon to return the collection.
}

fn main() {
    let result = go(1);
    println!("{:?}", result);

}
```

output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Apparently, a `return` inside an `if expression` is treated differently.  According to "Programming Rust (Revised 2nd Edition)", p. 146:

> Like a `break` expression, `return` can abandon work in progress.

Interestingly, the following doesn't produce any errors either:

```
fn go(x: i32) -> Vec<i32> {

    let result = if x == 2 {
        return (30..=35).collect();
    };

    return (0..=10).collect();
}
```

And, the compiler infers the type of `result` to be `()`.  So, either the assignment will be interrupted by the return and never happen, or if `x` is not equal to `2`, the if will evaluate to `()`--because "an if without an else must always [evaluate to] `()`"--and that value will get assigned to `result`.

---

Wouldn't it be simpler to let the user just hit Return to get the default range, or enter two numbers for a custom range?

```
println!("Enter two numbers for your range, or");
println!("simply hit Return to choose the range 1-10:");
```

There's a `Guess The Number` example program in [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html) that you might want to take a look at.

> Finally, any recommendations for small projects to build ?

Are you familiar with [exercism.org](https://exercism.org/)? You can sign up for the Rust track (free), then you'll be assigned a series of programs to complete.  If you have a github account (free), you can seamlessly download and submit your completed programs.  When you download an assignment, there will be a suite of tests that your program must pass--which serves as the specification for your assignment. After you submit your solution, a tutor will examine your program and suggest improvements until you iteratively arrive at a final solution.  Then you move on to the next program.

Comment: Most of what you said about exercism is false. There's no need for a GitHub account to download and work the exercises. There's no tutor automatically assigned for every submission, unless the student specifically asks for one. Also, although exercism is free but the quality of their exercises is pretty crappy.